# Running multiple projects in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-express

I'm running visual studio express 2012 on Windows 7 through Bootcamp.  I have a solution with several projects, and when I start debugging it runs the first project, but I can't start new instances of the others (when I right click and choose debug -> start new instance it is grayed out).

I tried creating a new solution with two blank projects and I have the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on Solution -> Common Properties -> Startup Project -> Multiple startup projects -> Choose "Start" actions in drop-down lists. Now start debugging as usual.

Comment: I have the same problem. I did what you proposed and it helps a little starting multiple projects at once. But still the "Start new instance" is greyed out. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click -> Debug -> Start New Instance is not available for all types of projects. Usually projects of the type class libraires have this option missing.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Even when its just a basic wpf application with no code other than the default stuff it doesn't work...

Comment: This is strange, let me try it out on my VS 2012 environment and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new instance of Visual studio in order to debug the other project.